# How to implement a get<T>() similar to that in nlohmann/json?

Tags: c++, templates, nlohmann-json

I'm writing a json library that has the same usage as nlohmann/json. But I'm having trouble understanding nlohmann's get() function. So I implemented a get() myself, but I think that my method is not very good, do you have any good solutions or suggest?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

bool func(bool) { return 1; }
int func(int) { return 2; }
double func(double) { return 3; }
string func(string&) { return string("4"); }
vector<int> func(vector<int>&) { return { 5 }; }
map<int, int> func(map<int, int>&) {
    map<int, int>a;
    a.emplace(6, 6);
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
T get() {
    static T t;
    return func(t);
}

int main() {
    cout << get<bool>();
    cout << get<int>();
    cout << get<double>();
    cout << get<string>();
    cout << get<vector<int>>()[0];
    cout << get<map<int, int>>()[6];
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you need those `func`s? If it's all about the template selecting an appropriate overload then I'd skip the implementation of the base template and turn all those `func`s into specialisations.

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). As you talk about a library that gets special relevance, as you'd not only spoil your own global namespace, but the one of everybody using your library (at least if placed into a header).

Comment: What's not "good" about your solution?

Comment: If you implement the json variant using `std::variant`, `get` becomes a simple wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way works, but

- requires default constructible types (so no `void`, reference, ...),
- types which do *"nothing"* (a RAII object using global mutex would be problematic for example). Even a log might be strange.
- You should care about conversion/promotion with overloading resolution (`get<char>` is ambiguous from your types, `get<void(*)()>` would call `func(bool)`, but fortunately would fail to compile too because of return type)

As alternative:

- as your set of types seems limited and no extensible,

  - you might used `if constexpr`:

    ```
    template <typename T>
    T get() {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>) {
            return true;
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
            return 42;
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>) {
            return 4.2;
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
            return "Hello world";
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<int>>) {
            return {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::map<int, int>>) {
            return {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
        } else {
            static_assert(always_false<T>::value);
        }
    }
    ```
  - or (full) specialization:

    ```
    template <typename T> T get(); // No impl, to specialize

    template <> bool get() { return true; }
    template <> int get() { return 42; }
    template <> double get() { return 4.2; }
    template <> std::string get() { return "Hello world"; }
    template <> std::vector<int> get() { return {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42}; }
    template <> std::map<int, int> get() { return {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; }
    ```
- Reusing your idea of dispatching but with a tag. (that allows extensible set of types, and template implementation)

  ```
  template <typename T> struct tag {};

  bool func(tag<bool>) { return true; }
  int func(tag<int>) { return 42; }
  double func(tag<double>) { return 4.2; }
  std::string func(tag<std::string>) { return string("Hello world"); }
  std::vector<int> func(tag<std::vector<int>>) { return {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42}; }
  std::map<int, int> func(tag<std::map<int, int>>) { return {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; }

  #if 0 // Allow extension and template
  template <typename T>
  UserTemplateType<T> func(tag<UserTemplateType<T>>) { return {}; }
  #endif

  template <typename T>
  T get() {
      return func(tag<T>{});
  }
  ```